# How to read a xml file and covert it to python code and run?

Tags: python, xml, compiler-construction

What I want to do is to read a xml file that contains some python code inside.
And then run these code.

For example, the xml file contains print 'Hello World'

I want to use a function such as like

def RunXML(xml):

This function will read the code from the xml file and execute it. In this case, the function RunXML will print 'Hello World'.

Appreciate for any help.

Comment: More details on what the xml should looks like could be appreciated. You should take a look at the way that SPRING convert XML command in JAVA, it will probably give you good insight. And also, mention what you've tried until now could be good. For instance I just got the impression that your question is "how to recode SPRING in python?"

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment. Sorry for the misunderstanding. The question is how to run python code inside python. It is a bit confused. You are right, it is something like recode SPRING in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute python code from python you can use `exec` function, about reading from xml - you didn't provide any information about xml file structure.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answer, that's exacatly what I want. Don't worry about the xml.

Comment: Just test the exec, it looks like it is quiet slow compare to just run the code straight away?

Comment: Yes, it is slow, but you can to improve the speed, if before use the `compile` function